# Running "ipconfig /displaydns" in cmd prompt still displays results even after I run "ipconfig /flushdns"

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, ipconfig

Whenever I run "ipconfig /displaydns" I get a long list of sites even after running "/flushdns." I thought my results should be empty considering /flushdns. Is this normal behavior? I also noticed that after I run /flushdns and browse the internet for a couple of hours, my list of cached sites doesn't really change. Google.com, for example isn't on the list but a bunch of sites I've never visited do show up in my DNS cache. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Can you try it with the network interface disconnected?  The cache will get populated as soon as a request is made, so if you have applications that talk to the internet all the time, the list will get populated immediately.

Comment: @Paul: Just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: What didn't work exactly?

Comment: @Paul: I switched my WiFi switch off on my laptop, then I ran /flushdns, then I ran /displaydns and again it showed about 15 sites or so, that I've never even been to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ipconfig /displaydns` will show both cached dns entries from previous lookups, along with any hardcoded DNS names, such as those found in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Review this file and delete any entries that aren't needed.  Usually, only

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

is required.

Answer (score 2):

If you install some anti virus programs, they will populate your DNS cache with ip addresses that will not flush. Apparently, those sites are deemed to be hazardous and remain in your cache. Spybot Search and Destroy does this. I found this out after I bought a new computer. I flushed my cache after I surfed for a few hours. Then I installed Spybot. When I flushed my cache then ran  ipconfig/ displaydns, many ip addresses remained. Each Spybot update put more ip addresses into the cache. Many of the addresses appeared to be casino/gambling and porn sites. Those ip addresses apparently help Spybot to prevent me from visiting those sites and prevented those sites from hijacking my computer.